# Como copiar as regras de validação em vba?

Tags: vba

```
If Range("L9") > (Range("I9") + Range("J9")) Then
       Range("B8:O8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

aqui eu quero copiar as regras de validação se este if acontecer

```
 End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,
Se eu entendi bem, você quer copiar a validação de dados, porém a validação de dados não pode ser copiada, mas você pode adicionar uma igual assim:

```
Range("B4").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="10"
```

Esse exemplo só deixa números de 1 a 10 na célula, você pode utilizar variáveis para copiar a validação.

Espero ter ajudado.